# Add custom element to wordpress homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like some advise about how to add a custom element (containing a textbox and a button) to my WordPress homepage.
What I would like to Achieve is to add an element where the user can write a code into a textbox.

Then the tricky part:
When the user clicks the button or hits enter, the code written in the textbox needs to be added in an URL variable like this "www.mysite.com/?uid=1234567890", where 1234567890 is the code the user wrote in the textbox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Assuming you're not a developer first,

#### Add to the sidebar

- After logging in to the WordPress admin panel, we follow the link "**Appearance**" and "**Widgets**" respectively.
- Click "**Custom HTML**" from the available widgets section and add it to an area allowed by the theme.
- After this process, a new section with "**title**" and "**content**" fields will appear on the right.
- If you want to add a title, it can be filled, otherwise leave it blank, add the code below to the part that says "**content**" and press the save button.

```html
<form method="get" action="/">
   <input type="text" name="uid" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

#### Add to the index

> Remember, since this process will make direct changes to the theme files, it is useful to make a backup to a text editor first.

- After logging in to the WordPress admin panel, we follow the link "**Appearance**" and "**Theme Editor**" respectively.
- Click on the "`home.php`" link if it exists in the navigation menu on the right of the page that appears, or "`index.php`" if not. (**Main Index Template**) can write.
- If you want it to appear after the articles on the homepage, paste it before the `<?php get_footer();` command. Otherwise paste after `get_header(); ?>` command.

```html
<form method="get" action="/">
   <input type="text" name="uid" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

> If you encounter any problems or errors. Delete everything inside the changed file and copy and paste it again from where you backed up. That way, you'll have a chance to try again.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.
I am a .net developer, I just don't have that much experience working with WordPress.
Again thanks for helping me out here.